# CSS property overriden. Why?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

Why is the `h2` selector honored here? I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be.

```css
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: #204466;
}
figure.portfolio-item > figcaption {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<figure class="portfolio-item">
  <figcaption>
    <h2>The title</h2>
    <p>
      The content.
    </p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Can you add code snippet

Comment: show us your html please

Comment: Are you sure the h2 selector is the one in force? I was about to reply "Specificity!" but the second selector is not matching any h2's.

Comment: @Gowtham Added code snippet

Comment: @jedifans I'm 99% sure. Checked by inspecting in chrome. I know what specificity is :P

Comment: @jedifans Oh I see! Yeah it isn't. But shouldn't the value be inherited still? Also in my project the p isn't white as well. :P

Comment: Fixed. I needed to specify h2 and p. Sorry stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to override `h2` style for instance, you should be giving it like this:

```
figure.portfolio-item > figcaption h2 {
  color: #333 !important;
}
```

The style will `inherit` but `h2` has more precedence over that.

```css
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: #204466;
}
figure.portfolio-item > figcaption h2 {
  color: #333 !important;
}
```

```html
<figure class="portfolio-item">
  <figcaption>
    <h2>The title</h2>
    <p>
      The content.
    </p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd selector you aren't selecting the `h2` directly, so select the `h2`, to override the "general rule" applied before in `h2`

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: #204466;
}
figure.portfolio-item > figcaption h2, figure.portfolio-item > figcaption p {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<figure class="portfolio-item">
  <figcaption>
    <h2>The title</h2>
    <p>
      The muthafucking content.
    </p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: The very fact that the second rule isn't targeting the h2 at all means that this is *not* an issue of specificity.